# Comparison of Depth First Search Trees

Tags: algorithms, search-trees

Does anyone know of an algorithm who is able to return how similar a DFS Tree is from another DFS Tree? (Or any kind of tree in general)

I'm not looking for a true or false. Instead, I would like it to return something in the form of "DFS A is ~87% similar to DFS B"

Thanks!

Comment: How do you define "similarity" between two trees?

Comment: Good point. For this case, a recommender system, I have to measure how a product is similar to another one. The product description is a DFS Tree. So, if I have a tree A of height 1, and the data inserted in each of its nodes are equals to the data in the nodes of a tree B (height 1), A and B are equals.

Comment: Look into Tree Edit Distance.